# Convert Hex STDIN / ARGV / gets to ASCII in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, hex, stdin

my Question is how I can convert the STDIN of cmd ARGV or gets from hex to ascii

I know that if I assigned hex string to variable it'll be converted once I print it

ex

```
hex_var = "\x41\41\x41\41"
puts hex_var
```

The result will be

> AAAA

but I need to get the value from command line by (ARGV or gets)

say I've this lines

```
s = ARGV

puts s
# another idea
puts s[0].gsub('x' , '\x')
```

then I ran

```
ruby  gett.rb \x41\x41\x41\x41
```

I got

> \x41\x41\x41\x41

is there a way to get it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems you're dealing with here. The first you've already tried to address, but I don't think your solution is really ideal. The backslashes you're passing in with the command line argument are being evaluated by the shell, and are never making it to the ruby script. If you're going to simply do a gsub in the script, there's no reason to even pass them in. And doing it your way means *any* 'x' in the arguments will get swapped out, even those that aren't being used to indicate a hex. It would be better to double escape the \ in the argument if possible. Without context of where the values are coming from, it's hard to say with way would actually be better.

```
ruby gett.rb \\x41\\x41
```

That way ARGV will actually get '\x41\x41', which is closer to what you want.

It's still not exactly what you want, though, because ARGV arguments are created without expression substitution (as though they are in single quotes). So Ruby is escaping that \ even though you don't want it to. Essentially you need to take that and re-evaluate it as though it were in double quotes.

```
eval('"%s"' % s)
```

where s is the string.

So to put it all together, you could end up with either of these:

```
# ruby gett.rb \x41\x41

ARGV.each do |s|
  s = s.gsub('x' , '\x')
  p eval('"%s"' % s)
end
# => "AA"

# ruby gett.rb \\x41\\x41

ARGV.each do |s|
  p eval('"%s"' % s)
end
# => "AA"
```

Comment: `ARGV.each do |s|
  s = s.gsub('x' , '\x')
  p eval('"%s"' % s)
end`

Comment: Thanks @farski , actually I wasn't know about eval (newcomer). it works great with my case. I've to read more about it.
thanks

Comment: Try `ruby gett.rb "#{system('touch ~/security-fail')}"`. Then think what would happen if someone used that with say `rm -rf`... You better not use `eval` unless your trust all current and future users 100%. Perhaps not even then.

Comment: @LarsHaugseth Thanks Lars,, 
Still don't know much about eval and it's security issues , on another hand I'll use it in my own scripts

Answer (score 1):

Backlashes entered in the console will be interpreted by the shell and will
not make it into your Ruby script, unless you enter two backlashes in a row,
in which case you script will get a literal backlash and no automatic
conversion of hexadecimal character codes following those backlashes.

You can convert these escaped codes to characters manually if you replace the last line of your script with this:

```
puts s.gsub(/\\x([[:xdigit:]]{1,2})/) { $1.hex.chr }
```

Then run it with double backlashed input:

```
$ ruby gett.rb \\x41\\x42\\x43
ABC
```

When fetching user input through *gets* or similar, only a single backslash will be need to be entered by the user for each character escape, since that will indeed be passed to your script as literal backslashes and thus handled correctly by the above *gsub* call.

---

An alternative way when parsing command line arguments would be to let the shell interpret the character escapes for you. How to do this will depend on what shell you are using. If using *bash*, it can be done
like this:

```
$ echo $'\x41\x42\x43'
ABC
$ ruby -e 'puts ARGV' $'\x41\x42\x43'
ABC
```

Comment: thanks @Lars but I'll use long hex numbers to I can't apply a backslash for each byte. 

for the second solution is not working for me. I'm dealing with OptionParser class and when I print the option's argument it prints the hex again, in my case I've to convert its to ASCII in order to do another tasks

I got good info from you guys , thanks.